# TinyMCE Custom Tags Rendering

Tags: templates, tinymce, templatetags

I have add a custom plugin that insert custom tags into my tinyMCE editor of the format:

title

I want the custom tags to be rendered with some styles when viewed in the WYSIWYG view. I have seen one response to a similar question :

http://topsecretproject.finitestatemachine.com/2010/02/how-to-custom-tags-with-tinymce/

but this doesn't work - they tags are not stripped out but they are not styled either??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [content_css](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css) initialisation parameter:

```
content_css: my_css_file.css
```

containing something like

```
title {
  // css here
}
```